# Como poner el formato de fecha dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: json, spring-boot, swagger

El Spring ignora la anotaciones teno el campo DTO asi.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate fecha;
```

pero cuando vamos al Swager a mirar el ejemplo que nos da lo pone asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No coge el orden ni las barras.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Schema(type = "string", pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", example = "17-02-2020")
private LocalDate fecha;
```

La clave esta en no poner el format ya que si no usamos el metodo ingles de mes dia año, no nos cogera el formato que queremos.

Comment: ¿Puedes dejar de editar publicaciones cambiando **arreglo** por **array**?

Comment: Abrí una [publicación en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5465/169744) para que el asunto de **arreglo** por **array** sea resuelto. Si tienes algo que decir al respecto, pásate por ahí.